# Scroll a ScrollView containing fragments to a specific fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` where I create multiple `Fragments` under specific conditions. I want when I add a new fragment to the ScrollView to make it scroll so the `Fragment` is at the top most part of the screen. Here is my code :

From `Fragment` I call this inside `onCreateView` (As `Fragments` are generated dynamically)

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).scrollToFrag(frag_number+"");
```

**And inside my MainActivity.class**

```
public final void scrollToFrag(final String frag){
    scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(frag).getView().getTop());
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I notice a small scroll movement but not what I need ( The `Fragment` not reach the top at all)

Comment: did you try `scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0)` ?

Comment: I'm calling this code from the Activity not the fragment, calling this will scroll to the top most of the Activity where ever my fragment.

Comment: did you see what does it return ? `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(frag).getView().getTop()`, anyway if you are sure your recently added fragment should be shown at top then you should pass hardcoded value as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by running the code in a runnable inside the Fragment as well

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).scrollToFrag(frag_number+"");
                }
            }, 200);
```